# Store list or collection in Apache Avro schema

Tags: list, collections, schema, avro

I'm currently creating Avro schema to store twitter data streams.
My data source in JSON:

```
{
'id': '123456789',
'text': 'bla bla bla...',
'entities': {
  'hashtags': [{'text':'hashtag1'},{'text':'hashtag2'}]
  }
}
```

in Cassandra, I can define collection (sets or lists) to store hashtags data.
But I have no idea how to define this structure in Apache Avro.

Here's my best try:

```
{"namespace": "ln.twitter",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "main",
 "fields": [
   {"name": "id","type": "string"},
   {"name": "text","type": "string"},
   {"name": "hashtags","type": "string"} // is there any better format for this ?
 ]
}
```

Need your advice please.

Thanks,
Yusata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `entities` field needed explicit records (or maps) inside. Here's a schema that should work:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Main",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "text",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "entities",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Entities",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "hashtags",
            "type": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Hashtag",
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "text",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In case it's helpful, you can use [this tool](http://mtth.github.io/avsc/infer.html) to generate an (anonymous) Avro schema from any valid JSON record. You'll then just need to add names to the `record` types.

You can try it on your example after switching its `'` to `"`:

```
{
  "id": "123456789",
  "text": "bla bla bla...",
  "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "hashtag1"}, {"text": "hashtag2"}]}
}
```